# Setting secure flag for antiforgery cookies in Asp.Net Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

I just can't figure out how to require SSL for antiforgery cookies stored in clients browsers. The actual authentication cookie is marked as `secure` and `httponly` as expected.

Where do you define this? In `cookie` options? In `antiforgery` options? Is it even necessary or reasonable?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I'm confused. If the cookie already has the `Secure` flag, then you are requiring SSL already. What is it that you're actually looking for here?

Comment: I noticed, that the antiforgery cookie is missing the secure flag. E.g. using the Firefox debugging tools, the web storage tab shows a "true" for the .AspNetCore.Cookies item, but for .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.<id> it shows a "false" and I'm wondering how to influence this behavior.